# How to register alternate mp3-viewer for the filebrowser app "myfiles"?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am creating an mp3tag editor and want it to get started via the android-buildin-filebrowser "myfiles" (com.sec.android.app.myfiles/com.sec.android.app.myfiles.MainActivity) .

When i select a mp3 file i get an activity chooser that offers me two programs to execute the file.
Unfortunately my own program is not among the offered choises.

However if i use the external android-filebrowser [OI File Manager](http://www.openintents.org/en/filemanager) it offers me a chooser
which includes my own app.

My question: how do i have to register my actrivity in the manifest so that "myfiles" can launch it?

My app is registered like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="media.mp3"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".Mp3TagEditorActivity" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.EDIT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
                    <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg"  />

                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Which built in file browser does Android come with? That's news to me. Sound like an HTC Sense thing or something. They probably don't scan for the VIEW or EDIT intent like OI

Comment: my german galaxy fit has an icon "Eigene Dateien" which is logged as [myfiles]

Comment: Which two programs does my files offer you to open the file with? The default Music app and something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am creating an mp3tag editor and want it to get started via the android-buildin-filebrowser "myfiles".

There is no "android-buildin-filebrowser 'myfiles'" in the Android OS. You may be thinking of a file browser that ships on some specific device.

> My question: how do i have to register my actrivity in the manifest so that "myfiles" can launch it?

To answer that definitively, you would have to contact the author of "myfiles".

> My app is registered like this:

Your `<intent-filter>` is rather wrong.

First, `EDIT` and `VIEW` are actions, not categories.

Second, the only way it will match on your `<intent-filter>` is if the `LAUNCHER` category is included, which is very unlikely for the `EDIT` or `VIEW` actions.

If you want this activity to both be in the home screen's launcher *and* respond to `VIEW` or `EDIT` actions, you would need something like this:

```
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Mp3TagEditorActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg"  />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Two separate `<intent-filter>` elements are a logical OR -- any `Intent` that matches the first *or* the second will match this activity.

Comment: after adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` in the lower 
`<intent-filter >` this solution worked for me. tks

Comment: @k3b: Ah, yeah, sorry -- for activities, you always have to have some category.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It may be as simple as adding:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
```

So your Manifest should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="media.mp3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Mp3TagEditorActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.EDIT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg"  />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Give that a try and you may likely show up for your myfiles app. Hope that resolves your issue.

Comment: `INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER` would be for an activity that *is* a music player, not a tag editor. Also, if you are going to go that route, since `INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER` is deprecated, also consider moving to [`CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC) for Android 4.0+.